# How can I refresh the cache of model manually in rake file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I refresh the cache of model manually

I can cached pages with fragment,

and refresh it in outside rake task

But I have no idea how to refresh the cache inside the controller for fetching data from DB.

How could I refresh the cache in Rake file

```
def get_max_and_min_routes(airline_name, from, to)
  Rails.cache.fetch("I_AM_CACHE_KEY") do
    FETCH_FROM_DB
  end
end
```

## rake file

```
action_controller = ActionController::Base.new
action_controller.expire_fragment("body_header")
action_controller.expire_fragment("index")
action_controller.expire_fragment("welcome_index_controller")
action_controller.expire_fragment("footer")
```

## index.haml

```
- cache("index", skip_digest: true) do
  = render "historical_prices"
= render "common/recently_changed_prices"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the cache directly through the `Rails.cache` command like so:

```
> Rails.cache.read('body_header')
=> '<p>fragment cache entry</p>'
> Rails.cache.delete('body_header')
 => true 
> Rails.cache.read('body_header')
 => nil
```

So for your example:

```
def get_max_and_min_routes(airline_name, from, to)
  content_to_be_cached = FETCH_FROM_DB
  Rails.cache.write('body_header', content_to_be_cached)
end
```

This should work in your rake file and also from the console.

Comment: But i dont think the write function make sense, because who would've know how the query result will be look like

Comment: You would put the output of your `FETCH_FROM_DB` code into the cache like. I've edited the above response.